# Change Domain Name Forest Root

Tags: active-directory, domain, rename, windows-dns

- Forest Root Name is abc123.com
- The only domain in the forest is
  abc123.com
- I want to add a new Domain called newxyz.com as a Tree Domain, non-contiguous domain.
- Using a 2way transitive trust I would like to slowly migrate all
  department objects such as users over to the new
  newxyz.com  domain while allowing members of newxyz.com to access shared resources
  such as our NAS, printers, etc...  on abc123.com.
- Once everything has been migrated over to newxyz.com domain, I want to get rid of abc123.com
  and make newxyz.com  the new Forest Root Domain and Forest Name.

Is all this even possible?
Is there a better way to do this.
I do not want to use any port tools because we had recovered from a virus attack and I don't want to bring anything over, I will do all of this manually for every user, object, etc...

Comment: Why not a new forest? Do you have Exchange?

Comment: Thank you for the question Greg.  I decided to just create a new forest and create a 2 way transitive Forest Trust since I am rebuilding the entire old domain in the new domain.  that way I can hopefully do this department by department and bring everything that each department needs and uses - like their printers, and give them access to our NAS in the old domain.  We have Office 365 and I plan to use Azure Hybrid integration with the new domain.  The reason for the domain change is that we do not own the existing domain name so we cannot use it for email, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I read a Microsoft Article, that seems to answer my question.
[Selecting the Forest Root Domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/selecting-the-forest-root-domain) is the name of the article.

Extrapolation from article:
"The first domain that you deploy in an Active Directory forest is called the forest root domain. ***This domain remains the forest root domain for the life cycle of the AD DS deployment.***"